# Does "the initial phase of oscillation is 45°" mean a time dependence of the form $\sin(\omega t+\pi/4)$ or $\cos(\omega t+\pi/4)$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, harmonic-oscillator, conventions

> A point particle of mass 0.1 kg is executing SHM with an amplitude 0.1 m. When the particle passes through the mean position, its kinetic energy is $8 \times 10^{-3}$ Joule. Obtain the equation of motion of this particle if the initial phase of oscillation is 45 degrees.

I have found out $\omega$ to be 4 rad/s.

However, I don't understand, which of the two will be the equation of motion. Are both possible? Why?

$$y=0.1\sin\left(\omega t+ \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

or

$$y=0.1\cos\left(\omega t+ \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

Comment: The difference between the two is just the phase. Physically this just means starting with a different initial position.

Comment: @AaronStevens So either of the two is correct?

Comment: I'm not sure. It seems like there is some missing information.

Answer (score 2):

*Absolute* phase is never uniquely defined for cyclic motion - only relative phases are, unless one explicitly defines a phase reference. This means that either

1. the text that contains this question also contains an explicit convention for how to handle absolute phases, which you're not reporting, so that the question does have an answer but you have not presented enough information for anyone to tell what that is, or
2. the text doesn't contain such a convention, and the question is entirely unanswerable.

Either way, the information you've presented is insufficient to answer the question.